# detect and strip out any foreign text, while keeping special characters

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am trying to filter out all non latin characters, such as `γειά σου` with javascript / regex, while allowing special characters such as `!@#$%^&*()`.
 
But if JS is not possible then php with `preg_replace` perhaps. 
Ive tried JS `str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\-.,:;]/i, "");` but that didnt do anything. 
With php `$str = preg_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9\xC0-\xFF]', '', $str);` but got the same results.

This `echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");` however gave me garbled text,[image] 
maybe i can somehow detect that?

Q: what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your JS regex has an invalid delimiter mashup, your PHP variant has none. And why are you applying the `ISO-8859-1` charset on `UTF-8` text?

Comment: @mario i saw a post that suggested using php and tried it, but obviously that wasnt the correct approach

Comment: javascript doesn't support unicode.

Comment: in this question does 'non latin' = not in 8859-1 ?

Comment: @Dagon yes. Meaning i would like to keep this "american english" letters and special characters found on common keyboards sold in america

Comment: `str = str.replace(/[^ -~]+/g, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to be working when i tested it, but you will want to double check:

```
$output = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $output);
```